# Code First - Non Required Field Is Required

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, sql-server-2016

I have entity Program that has two foreign keys to my subject table (MainContactSubjectId, SecondaryContactSubjectId). Both main and secondary are nullable longs. For some reason, when I try to insert entity Program it errors (Internal Server Error) and will not let me insert unless Main and Secondary are present. Below is my entity Program and some of my dbContext. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
    [Table("Program")]
    public class Program : Entity<long>
    {

        [Required]
        public int TenantId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public long ProgramTypeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(4000)]
        public string ProgramName { get; set; }

        public long? MainContactSubjectId { get; set; }

        public long? SecondaryContactSubjectId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AppTables.Case_ProgramRequirements.Case_ProgramRequirement> Case_ProgramRequirement { get; set; }
        public virtual AppTables.ProgramTypes.ProgramType ProgramType { get; set; }
        public virtual AppTables.Subjects.Subject MainSubject { get; set; }
        public virtual AppTables.Subjects.Subject SecondarySubject { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm guessing the problem is here but I'm not sure what it is. My best
guess is the .HasRequired but I'm not sure how to rewrite it. 
Without this code, the foreign keys are not getting created correctly 
and circular reference issues. The WillCascadeOnDelete(false) stops the 
circular reference issue.

```
public virtual IDbSet<AppTables.Programs.Program> Programs { get; set; }


protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
            modelBuilder.Entity<AppTables.Programs.Program>()
                    .HasRequired(m => m.MainSubject)
                    .WithMany(t => t.ProgramsMain)
                    .HasForeignKey(m => m.MainContactSubjectId)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<AppTables.Programs.Program>()
                    .HasRequired(m => m.SecondarySubject)
                    .WithMany(t => t.ProgramsSecondary)
                    .HasForeignKey(m => m.SecondaryContactSubjectId)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

Edit 1:
I am fairly confident my problem is in the data access layer but if not, I am making an ajax call directly to my Application Service layer "Create". As I step through it everything looks perfect. It hits the return and then I get Internal Server Error. No other details. I tried wrapping in try/catch and catch is never hit.

I am using Asp.net Boilerplate framework. I have posted in their private forum too with no luck, yet. I just assumed it was a data access layer issue which is why I posted here.

```
public async Task<> Create(ProgramInput model)
    {
            Program domainModel = new Program();
            domainModel.TenantId = (int)AbpSession.TenantId;
            domainModel.ProgramName = model.ProgramName;
            domainModel.ProgramTypeId = model.ProgramTypeId;
            domainModel.MainContactSubjectId = model.MainContactId;
            domainModel.SecondaryContactSubjectId = model.SecondaryContactId;
            domainModel.CreatedBy = (long)AbpSession.UserId.Value;
            domainModel.CreatedDate = Clock.Now;
            domainModel.IsDeleted = false;

            await _programRepository.InsertAsync(domainModel);

            return;
    }
```

Edit 2:
Here is my Subject Table. It has 50 some columns and 10 foreign keys but I will shorten with just the pertinent data.

```
public class Subject : Entity<long>
{
    public Subject()
    {
        this.ProgramsMain = new HashSet<AppTables.Programs.Program>();
        this.ProgramsSecondary = new HashSet<AppTables.Programs.Program>();
    }

    [Required]
    public int TenantId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long SubjectTypeId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(1000)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(1000)]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(1000)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Suffix { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(3000)]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
//A TON MORE COLUMNS ....




    public virtual AppTables.SubjectTypes.SubjectType SubjectType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AppTables.Programs.Program> ProgramsMain { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AppTables.Programs.Program> ProgramsSecondary { get; set; }
```

**ANSWER**
I figured out my answer. I switched .HasRequired to .HasOptional and everything now works. Sorry to have wasted everyone's time. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the error is in data access layer? What about your controller? Please specify more info about the channel that directs the data to insert.

Comment: What does ProgramsMain and ProgramsSecondary look like?

Comment: I figured out my answer. I switched .HasRequired to .HasOptional and everything now works. Sorry to have wasted everyone's time. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps do a formal answer to your own question? It will help others a lot as most people will probably not read the comments to see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the OP's answer in his question edit and comment:

Change .HasRequired to .HasOptional as per the code below.

```
public virtual IDbSet<AppTables.Programs.Program> Programs { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<AppTables.Programs.Program>()
                .HasOptional(m => m.MainSubject)
                .WithMany(t => t.ProgramsMain)
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.MainContactSubjectId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AppTables.Programs.Program>()
                .HasOptional(m => m.SecondarySubject)
                .WithMany(t => t.ProgramsSecondary)
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.SecondaryContactSubjectId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```